# Multiple checkboxes in Bootstrap with a custom last option

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a cosmetic question, but I've got a form for sending out messages to predefined recipients and/or to custom recipients. But if you run the example you'll notice a small vertical alignment problem with the checkbox and the textbox for the last option (Ideally the checkbox would vertically aligned to the center of the textbox). I could manually override the top margin of the checkbox with an inline style of 10px, but I'm hoping there is an option that doesn't rely on an assumption of textbox size? I've tried the input-group or form-inline for just the last option, but none seem to be quite right and tend to make it worse.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Recipient Types</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" />Send to Sales Department
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" />Send to HR Department
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```